# Logging Spring bean initialization with Log4J

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, javabeans

When I run my application, it stops when beans are initializing but doesn't show any logs entries. So I don't know what happened:

**Log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
org.springframework=DEBUG
org.springframework.beans.factory.support=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory.support=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace 
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=debug
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %t %C{1}- %m%n
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${log4j.appender.R.File}
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=0
log4j.appender.R.Append=true
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %t (%l) - %m%n
```

I want to get something like:

```
"BeanName" initialized 
"BeanName" initialized
etc...
```

So then I would know where the initialization stopped. Is it possible to get such an output in the logs, when beans are initializing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set "**org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory**" to **debug** level. The output looks something like this:

```
... - Creating instance of bean ...
... - Finished creating instance of bean  ...
```

**Update:**

Add this to log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory=DEBUG
```

Keep in mind that Spring is using the **commons-logging framework**, therefore these lines will not appear in your Log4J logs. To **redirect** them use [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html). Add [slf4j-api.jar, jcl-over-slf4j.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j) and log4j.jar to your lib directory and remove commons-logging.jar from it.

Comment: I already have all of this dependencies in my pom.xml and commons-logging has `<scope>provided</scope>` Maybe i have to add this log4j.properties somewhere?

Comment: Commons-logging must be excluded. And remove 'org.springframework=DEBUG'
and 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support=DEBUG' lines from the properties file.

Comment: I done everything what you say but still nothing i have log4j.properties looks like you want and it's in src/main/resources/properties/ directory.

Comment: Put it in src/main/resources/ only

Comment: After move this file to src/main/resources it works !

Answer (score 3):

Add to your log4j xml (check if you already have one with lavel ERROR, change it either INFO or DEBUG

```xml
<logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="INFO" />
</logger>
```