# how to set debug logging for spring framework using java configuration

Tags: java, spring

I have seen a video whereby they enable debug logging for spring framework in a spring boot project. they created an application.properties file and entered `logging.level.org.springframework = debug` in the file.

I would like to do same for my application but I am not using spring boot. I have added dependencies like log4j but I am not sure about the settings.

Can someone share a link please?

thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468999/enabling-logging-in-spring This has already been answered

Comment: I read it. it is still not working.

Comment: I used this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285710/logging-spring-bean-initialization-with-log4j